# Hibernate/JPA - Update an entity field that also contains a date field with @Future

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, save

I have an entity that has a date field annotated with @Future. I create the record/transaction initially with a given date (let's say tomorrows date 5/31/21) using repository.save(data). - Works Fine!

```
public class data{

  @Future
  private Date date;

  private String status;

}
```

5/31/2021

```
data data = new data(LocalDateTime.now(), "initialstatus")
repository.save(data);
```

I then come in on 6/1/21 and update a different field called "status", but when I go to make the update I get an error that the transaction can't be committed, and I am guessing because it's trying to save the 5/31/21 date in the @Future date field on 6/1/21 (which is not a future date at this point) while trying to update the status field.

6/1/2021

```
data data = repository.findById(id).get();
data.setStatus("updatedstatus");
repository.save(data);
```

```
2021-05-30 09:46:13.597 DEBUG 10984 --- 
[nio-8080-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
[org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: 
Error while committing the transaction]
```

Once I remove the @Future, I can update the status field, so my question is how can I update just the status field and not the date field where it's failing because the date is now in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this can be done if you need to validate only on insert using validation groups.
Does this answer your question: [Hibernate validations on save (insert) only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964065/hibernate-validations-on-save-insert-only)?

Comment: Yeah, groups could work, I just didn't want to have to spin up a group to do a simple thing (or at least what I was hoping was simple)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `updatable` attribute of the `@Column` annotation to `false`:

```
@Column(updatable= false)
@Future
private Date date;
```

The `updatable` attribute instruct Hibernate to omit this column from the generated `UPDATE` SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @DynamicUpdate. Entity will use dynamic sql generation where only changed columns get referenced.

```
@DynamicUpdate
public class data{

  @Future
  private Date date;

  private String status;

}
```